# Are there any Linux alternatives to libgpod for reading/writing iPod databases?

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I am writing a C program to sync my iPod, in the same spirit as [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/) but for the console. Gtkpod uses their own library, [libgpod](http://gtkpod.org/wiki/Libgpod), for connecting to ipod dbs. I want to know if there are any GObject/GLib-free libraries available that I could use instead of libgpod.

Answer (score 1):

There's [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/), but that seems to be lower level and more general than libgpod. Maybe it could help you though.

Comment: libimobiledevice doesn't support music transfer and libgpod does, so you can't replace with it in every situation